# Error regarding labels in Rstudio when trying to match labels to the values

Tags: r

```
ski_suit <- dem_e*slope_e*distance_e
ski_suit[ski_suit<=5] <- NA
ski_suit[ski_suit>=6&ski_suit<=9] <- 1
ski_suit[ski_suit>9] <- 2
labels <- data.frame(
  values=c(NA,1,2),
  labels=c('NA','Not Suitable','Suitable')

tm_shape(ski_suit)+
  tm_raster(style='cat',labels='Not Suitable','Suitable'[[1]],palette='-BrBG')
```

Above is the code that I am using, whenever I plot using plot() for example, the map prints out just fine with labels 1 and 2. When I try to input labels into my map, I receive the error "invalid 'labels'; length 3 should be 1 or 2".

Instead of `labels='NA','Not Suitable', 'Suitable'` I've tried using `labels=labels(ski_suit)` to no avail.

To add to this, I've also tried reclassifying by doing:

```
labels <- c("NA", "Not Suitable", "Suitable")
breaks <- c(0,1,2)

ski_rcl <- classify(ski_suit,breaks=breaks,labels=labels)
```

but with this, I end up with the error: Error in .local(x, ...) : argument "rcl" is missing, with no default
and instead if `reclassify()` is used, the error: `unable to find an inherited method for function ‘reclassify’ for signature ‘"SpatRaster"` comes up.

Answer (score 0):

This won't answer your full question, but I can assist with the reclassify() error (`unable to find an inherited method for function ‘reclassify’ for signature "SpatRaster"`)

Your raster objects were probably of SpatRaster type (suppose you have `r` as your loaded raster, you can check its class with `class(r)`). As per the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/3.6-26/topics/reclassify) for reclassify(), you should use Raster* objects. So you need to convert your object first.

In my case, I had a single-layer raster, so I did:

```
r_converted <- raster(r)
```

Then you can use reclassify() on r_converted.

More information (and the source that solved my problem) can be found [here](https://tmieno2.github.io/R-as-GIS-for-Economists/raster-data-object-classes.html).